# Problem comparing dates with if statement

Tags: java, date, if-statement, localdatetime

I've got a problem comparing.

The second "if" is always fulfilled even if the second condition of the "if" is false.

First, I had to use Timestamp.valueOf so I could transform LocalDateTime to Date ("a" is a type of data "Date"). What i want to do is compare if the current time is greater than a predetermined time (a.getFinFecha()), if so, return 1. If the current time is greater or equal to the predetermined time (a.getFinFecha()) less seven days and is lower than the pretermined date, I want to return 2. Else (which means if the current time is lower than a.getFinFecha() and lower than a.getFinFecha() less 7 days) return 3. The object I'm passing is lower than the pretermined date less 7 days and it returns 2. Never returns 3.

```
if (java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()).compareTo(a.getFinFecha()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()).getDate() >= (a.getFinFecha().getDate() - 7) && java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()).compareTo(a.getFinFecha()) <= 0) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 3;
        }
```

Comment: a.getFinFecha() is a Timestamp?

Comment: Nope, it is a Date

Comment: `a.getFinFecha().getDate() - 7` looks wrong to me.  You're just subtracting 7 from the day number of the date, without considering the month or year.

Comment: I think that works Sergio. I tried it with the date 30/08/2022 and the result is 3

Comment: That's actually true Nahuel, try it with the date 12/08/2022, it does not work.

Comment: So can you please clarify?  When  `getFinFecha()` is `12/8/2022`, what result do you expect, and what result do you actually get?  And what is the actual local date and time when you're getting that result (I don't know your timezone)?

Comment: (I'm assuming that when you said 12/08/2022, you meant 12 August, not 8 December).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I had to use Timestamp.valueOf so I could transform LocalDateTime to Date

No, you hadn't and you shoudn't. Avoid using deprecated methods like `getDate()` and make use of the `java.time` API. The simplest solution could be to convert the `Date` returned by `a.getFinFecha()` to `LocalDateTime` and compare according to your requierments:

```
private int yourMethod() {
    Instant instant        = Instant.ofEpochMilli(a.getFinFecha().getTime());
    LocalDateTime finFecha = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC); // or use appropriate offset for your use case
    
    if (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(finFecha)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(finFecha.minusDays(7))) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 3;
    }
}
```